# Nokia HERE maps: Remove circle

Tags: javascript, here-api

I have drawn a circle on the map, now I want to remove this circle, How do I do this?

```
var radiusCircle = new nokia.maps.map.Circle(
            [viewportCenter.latitude, viewportCenter.longitude],
            100000,
                    {
                fillColor: "#F004", 
                $id: "radiusCircle"
            }
        );
        Map.map.objects.add(radiusCircle);
```

I have tried, `radiusCircle.hide();` `radiusCircle.destroy()` `radiusCircle.remove();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nokia.maps.map.Circle` inherits from `MapObject` which has a [visibility](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.Object.html#topic-apiref__Object-visibility-property) property.

To hide the circle but leave the underlying object on the map use:

```
radiusCircle.set("visibility", false);
```

To remove any `MapObject` from a map use:

```
map.objects.remove(radiusCircle);
```

Comment: I tried this, `var marker = map.objects.get(radiusCircle.id);
  marker.destroy();` which did not work. Any idea why?

Comment: And how do I make this circle draggable?

Comment: Try looking at the [Draggable Shapes](http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/shapes/map-with-draggable-shapes.html) example in the API Explorer.

Comment: What argument does `get()` method accept?  `map.objects.get(?);` I thought it accepts marker object's id, but when I pass obj id, it says illegal parameter.

Comment: ie., I want to know how do I get my radiusCircle marker object through `map.objects.get()` if I know its id ?

Comment: The `Display` class inherits the `objects` attribute from [Container](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.Container.html). If you look at the API Documentation, you can see that the interface here is an [OList](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.util.OList.html) so the `get()` method accepts an index parameter. In your case, you will probably need to combine this with `indexOf()`